# Using ko.observableArrays without viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devextreme

I want to use knockout observables without the viewmodel. I simply want to use one observableArray as a data source for a DevExtreme data grid. So for now, my idea was fairly simple: I just declared a variable (shuttleList) as empty ko.observableArray. Later, I fill that up through an ajax request. My grid is set to that variable as data source.

However, nothing happens, as I change the array. Still, I have to manually replace the dataSource of the grid using its option method. What am I doing wrong?

```
shuttleList = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON('http://someCall?ID=' + id, function (e) {
    shuttleList(e.tourenList.find(x => x.title == 'Base').shuttleList);
});

var grid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: shuttleList,
    …
});
```

I *know* that this is not the way knockout is supposed to be used, but can I somehow make this work automatically – without doing some manual grid refreshing in the shuttleList.subscribe event?

By the way, just calling the grid's refresh()/repaint() methods doesn't help either. I haven't found a way around resetting its dataSource option yet.

```
grid.option('dataSource', shuttleList);
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think all you're missing is to initialize the knockout bindings with `ko.applyBindings`, and you can use a specific element when calling that function. The "view-model" can be as simple as object-brackets with your variable inside:

`ko.applyBindings({shuttleList}, document.getElementById("gridContainer"));`

```js
var shuttleList = ko.observableArray([]);
setTimeout(function(){shuttleList.push("success!")}, 1000);

ko.applyBindings({shuttleList}, document.getElementById("gridContainer"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span>waiting for update...</span><br/>
<span id="gridContainer" data-bind="text: shuttleList"></span>
```

Comment: If that doesn't work then the problem is probably within the dxDataGrid and how it's using the datasource. I don't have experience with that control so let me know if this answer isn't helpful and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this is not the way knockout is supposed to be used, but
>   can I somehow make this work automatically – without doing some manual
>   grid refreshing in the shuttleList.subscribe event?

The only way to make KO to update something *automagically* is creating dependency. So in your case you can create anonymous `computed` that will depend on `shuttleList` observable array:

```
ko.computed(function(){
    grid.option('dataSource', shuttleList());
});
```

As you can see the observable array is *called* there. That's what creates dependency. Now any change made within `shuttleList` array will re-evaluate the function passed to `computed` and grid's dataSource will be updated.

However it doesn't seem optimal solution because pushing even single value will cause whole grid to render. But if you data doesn't contain too many rows then this approach will work good.

Furthermore there is another drawback - since the `computed` creates one-way dependency you have no way to reflect changes on the `shuttleList` array by using grid's API methods.